# How do I use the find command?

Tags: matlab, command, find

How used the find command?, To choose a vector largest number between negative and positive
example:

a=[-15 7]

to choose the largest number regardless of sign

Answer (score 2):

Use `max`, not `find`:

```
[vv ii] = max(abs(a));
result = a(ii)
```

Note that the second output argument of `max` gives the *index* of the maximizing element (or the first of them, if there are more than one).